# How to find the longest sub-array within a threshold?

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, numpy

Let's say you have a sorted array of numbers `sorted_array` and a threshold `threshold`. What is the fastest way to find the longest sub-array in which all the values are within the threshold? In other words, find indices `i` and `j` such that:

1. `sorted_array[j] - sorted_array[i] <= threshold`
2. `j - i` is maximal

In case of a tie, return the pair with the smallest `i`.

I already have a loop-based solution, which I will post as an answer, but I'm curious to see if there's a better way, or a way that can avoid the loop using a vector-capable language or library like NumPy, for example.

Example input and output:

```
>>> sorted_array = [0, 0.7, 1, 2, 2.5]
>>> longest_subarray_within_threshold(sorted_array, 0.2)
(0, 0)
>>> longest_subarray_within_threshold(sorted_array, 0.4)
(1, 2)
>>> longest_subarray_within_threshold(sorted_array, 0.8)
(0, 1)
>>> longest_subarray_within_threshold(sorted_array, 1)
(0, 2)
>>> longest_subarray_within_threshold(sorted_array, 1.9)
(1, 4)
>>> longest_subarray_within_threshold(sorted_array, 2)
(0, 3)
>>> longest_subarray_within_threshold(sorted_array, 2.6)
(0, 4)
```

Comment: Your own solution is already linear-time, and I don't believe it's possible to go asymptotically faster for a single query (though I can't prove it).  If you want to handle many queries for different thresholds and can afford O(n) space and O(n log n) preprocessing time, you can build a table m[], with m[i] being the minimum threshold value that permits a subarray of length i.  Then each query can be answered in O(log n) time by binary-searching m[].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely, the OP's own answer is the best possible algorithm, as it is O(n). However, the pure-python overhead makes it very slow. However, this overhead can easily be reduced by compiling the algorithm using [numba](http://numba.pydata.org/), with the current version (0.28.1 as of this writing), there is no need for any manual typing, simply decorating your function with `@numba.njit()` is enough.

However, if you do not want to depend on [numba](http://numba.pydata.org/), there is a numpy algorithm in O(n log n):

```
def algo_burnpanck(sorted_array,thresh):
    limit = np.searchsorted(sorted_array,sorted_array+thresh,'right')
    distance = limit - np.arange(limit.size)
    best = np.argmax(distance)
    return best, limit[best]-1
```

I did run a quick profiling on my own machine of the two previous answers (OP's and Divakar's), as well as my numpy algorithm and the numba version of the OP's algorithm.

```
thresh = 1
for n in [100, 10000]:
    sorted_array = np.sort(np.random.randn(n,))
    for f in [algo_user1475412,algo_Divakar,algo_burnpanck,algo_user1475412_numba]:
        a,b = f(sorted_array, thresh)
        d = b-a
        diff = sorted_array[b]-sorted_array[a]
        closestlonger = np.min(sorted_array[d+1:]-sorted_array[:-d-1])
        assert sorted_array[b]-sorted_array[a]<=thresh
        assert closestlonger>thresh
        print('f=%s, n=%d thresh=%s:'%(f.__name__,n,thresh))#,d,a,b,diff,closestlonger)
        %timeit f(sorted_array, thresh)
```

Here are the results:

```
f=algo_user1475412, n=100 thresh=1:
10000 loops, best of 3: 111 µs per loop
f=algo_Divakar, n=100 thresh=1:
10000 loops, best of 3: 74.6 µs per loop
f=algo_burnpanck, n=100 thresh=1:
100000 loops, best of 3: 9.38 µs per loop
f=algo_user1475412_numba, n=100 thresh=1:
1000000 loops, best of 3: 764 ns per loop
f=algo_user1475412, n=10000 thresh=1:
100 loops, best of 3: 12.1 ms per loop
f=algo_Divakar, n=10000 thresh=1:
1 loop, best of 3: 1.76 s per loop
f=algo_burnpanck, n=10000 thresh=1:
1000 loops, best of 3: 308 µs per loop
f=algo_user1475412_numba, n=10000 thresh=1:
10000 loops, best of 3: 82.9 µs per loop
```

At 100 numbers, O(n^2) solution using numpy just barely beats the O(n) python solution, but quickly after, the scaling makes that algorithm useless. The O(n log n) keeps up even at 10000 numbers, but the numba approach is unbeaten everywhere.

Comment: Was thinking `np.searchsorted` could be used, but I wasn't able to here. So,  are the results okay? They look different to me with `algo_burnpanck`, if run on the sample provided in the question.

Comment: The two `assert`s in the testing code do test for the two conditions required by the OP (the given pair is below threshold, and there is no pair with a longer distance), except for the tie instruction. However `np.argmax` will always return the lowest index in case of a tie. So I'm pretty sure the results are ok...

Comment: If I run `algo_burnpanck` on the sample of the question, I get the exact same results.

Comment: Ah nice, sorry I mistakenly placed another number in the array. Smart solution really!

Comment: Now I'm wondering if there's a way to do this starting from an unsorted array without sorting it first. Can't really wrap my ahead around that one though...

Comment: I am quite convinced that there is nothing better O(n log n) for unsorted input, achievable e.g. by simply sorting the array as a first step.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simple loop-based solution in Python:

```
def longest_subarray_within_threshold(sorted_array, threshold):
    result = (0, 0)
    longest = 0
    i = j = 0
    end = len(sorted_array)
    while i < end:
        if j < end and sorted_array[j] - sorted_array[i] <= threshold:
            current_distance = j - i
            if current_distance > longest:
                longest = current_distance
                result = (i, j)
            j += 1
        else:
            i += 1
    return result
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a vectorized approach using [`broadcasting`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) -

```
def longest_thresh_subarray(sorted_array,thresh):
    diffs = (sorted_array[:,None] - sorted_array)
    r = np.arange(sorted_array.size)
    valid_mask = r[:,None] > r
    mask = (diffs <= thresh) & valid_mask
    bestcolID = (mask).sum(0).argmax()
    idx = np.nonzero(mask[:,bestcolID])[0]
    if len(idx)==0:
        out = (0,0)
    else:
        out = idx[0]-1, idx[-1]
    return out
```

Sample runs -

```
In [137]: sorted_array = np.array([0, 0.7, 1, 2, 2.5])

In [138]: longest_thresh_subarray(sorted_array,0.2)
Out[138]: (0, 0)

In [139]: longest_thresh_subarray(sorted_array,0.4)
Out[139]: (1, 2)

In [140]: longest_thresh_subarray(sorted_array,0.8)
Out[140]: (0, 1)

In [141]: longest_thresh_subarray(sorted_array,1)
Out[141]: (0, 2)

In [142]: longest_thresh_subarray(sorted_array,1.9)
Out[142]: (1, 4)

In [143]: longest_thresh_subarray(sorted_array,2)
Out[143]: (0, 3)

In [144]: longest_thresh_subarray(sorted_array,2.6)
Out[144]: (0, 4)
```

Comment: This algorithm is both memory-wise as well as from the point of view of the computational complexity inefficient. It is O(n^2), while the OP's own answer is O(n).

Comment: @burnpanck Appreciate the comment that came with the vote. Sure, it's feeding on memory resources as do most of the vectorized approaches and it's proving not any better than the already provided one in the other answer by OP. I guess it could be taken as an alternative one and could be useful when run on multi-core systems. I will keep this post :)